# How to set up simulation architecture, OO design

Tags: java, model-view-controller, design-patterns, simulation, oop

I'm building a simulation in Java. So, I'll break my simulation into two parts:

1) The simulation engine

2) The simulation model

Basically I want a little help (tips/advice) about how to split it up i.e. what goes where.

So I'm thinking that the engine will keep track of time. It will listen for events and when events arrive it will update the state of the simulation ( I'm building a discrete event simulation). The simulation model will have the GUI and it will get the logic and data from the actual engine. I'm thinking that the model will provide the actual events as input to the engine. I've been thinking about a car analogy where the engine is the body of the car and the model the driver. So I want it to behave like the driver(model) telling the car(engine) what to do i.e. when to turn when to break and what speed to go at etc

Do you think I'm tackling this in the right way? I can sense that I sound a little confusing and not very clear. So I'll just clarify that what I'm looking for is just some input to how I should split this up and what the responsibility of engine and model should actually be.

Also, I was wondering, if I were to implement the MVC design pattern, how would that fit in with the way I'm trying to break it up?

EDIT:

By model I mean that I want the simulation to have a set of specific rules which the engine then follows. As I'm building a road traffic simulator, the rules could be like, the distribution of cars, driver profiles, what cars may and may not do ( e.g. stop for red light) etc. So the model is like the "brain" of the simulation if you get what I mean, and then the engine being the actual simulation of the set of "rules" specified by the model. I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: What are you trying to simulate? It doesn't make sense (unless you're building a very generic framework for thousands of uses and millions of users) to separate the "engine" from the "model". Also, I can see that you do not apply a consistent definition to the word "model". Please start with describing the physics of your problem.

Comment: Sorry about that. Please see the edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be not very applicable, but for MVC approach (Model-View-Controller), which is rather wide-spread and accepted, controller seems to correspond to what you call engine. And model is just that -- bunch of simple dump Java objects with as little logic as possible, containing only attributes of real-world objects they represent.

So, employing this analogy with MVC you'll get your model as set of roads, cars, containing just coordinates of objects and the engine will move cars, detect collisions etc.

After round of moves is finished, you'll get an updated version of model (some cars are in new positions with new velocity, some buildings are burning (heh), etc). And you'll handle this updated model to your view (whatever it may be) for rendering.

The only thing I'm unsure here is what part of the system is going to provide input events. In usual MVC this is some external entity (usually human operator). If by events you mean human input, it will be the same for your application. If you mean events like collisions because of, say, car's movements -- then it's engine itself who will produce such events as the result of calculations on each step of simulation.

Although, this not very classic OO design. In classic OO design, you would get model classes, such as cars, having their internal logic, which would define that, say, car is suddenly changes it's velocity out of the blue. I wouldn't go this route, because it makes logic of your code distributed between model classes and controller classes. You have set of model objects at the start of the world and the only way forward is to either influence them with engine decisions or to have real external input (like GUI input from human). If you need model object to change it's behavior, it should be responsibility of engine code, not model code.

Sorry for this rather incohesive speculation, this is rather wide topic and there are lots of books about such things.

Comment: Really good answer. I find it very helpful so no need at all to apologize for the in-cohesive speculation :)

In this simulation the input events will be a mixture of external entities (human) AND the logic of the simulation itself which will provide the events for example a crash. In terms of user interaction , I'm thinking closure of roads, which then causes the drivers to find an alternative shortest route (e.g. dijkstra's algorithm). 

Anyway, I like how you matched it up against the MVC design pattern, it helped clear some things up and gave me a few ideas on how to set it up. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't given us enough information to REALLY help sketch out your simulation, but here's a good tip: Anything that you can identify as a thing should be an object. So make a class `Car`. And a class `TrafficLight`. Then make a class `Driver`, each `Car` has a field `Driver`. And a `Road` would have a `List<Car>`

Before you start thinking about how to implement an MVC framework, make sure you understand [what it is.](http://www.larryullman.com/2009/10/08/understanding-mvc/). The most important thing about MVC is that it's about how the user interacts with a universe. So you'd want MVC if, for example, you were writing a game called SimTraffic, because not only do you need a traffic simulation, but the user needs to control it somehow too. If you were just watching a simulation occur (with no interaction), don't worry about MVC.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I found the link useful to add to my knowledge of MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the GUI. Please start from the physics - there are scores of traffic simulations; I assume you have read at least one book on the subject, if not it is high time to do so: a starting point could be a Springer-published collection of essays on various modern models called Fundamentals of Traffic Simulation (ISBN 1441961410), Jaume Barcelo (ed.) (2010).

EDIT: Would advise first deciding on the scope of your sim; what are the constant assumptions? For what time periods will it be tuned? Will road network change? Do you allow for car crashes, DUI idiots, onlookers taking movies from the crash site for Youtube?

What accuracy do you need from the sim - do you want it to be used for city planning, environmental control or traffic management? What are the variables and parameters that you set? Have you got statistical data to validate your simulation and test predictions against? Do you have ready data on physical characteristics of cars/drivers in your modelled universe/city (acceleration, linear size, propensity to break traffic rules)? There are a bunch of questions that should be answered **before** you sit down to code...

EDIT #2: from your comment to @Victor Sorokin 's answer, I gather you have a nice idea of adding driver's expectations into the model - would make the driver's AI the first thing to code: yes, shortest path, but the solution to the shortest path problem comes from stale data (with possibly variable delay). If you give drivers perfect foresight, there won't be any crashes; if you make them imperfect, you will have to model sensory input, perhaps boiled down to direction-specific probabilities of detecting an incoming car. It makes for some huge expenditure of CPU cycles, for sure.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation

Comment: The accuracy I need for the sim is as following. I will have a network of roads which will initially have a random distribution of cars coming in. There will be junctions at which there will be traffic lights. I will have more vehicles being distributed around rush hour time which will result in queues. The queues will affect the driver profiles, which in turn will lead to greater chances of collisions. The actual collision will NOT go into detail. it will be minimally animated but only from a 2d perspective and the collision will have an effect on the relevant roads

Comment: Firthermore, the roads will be able to be closed and opened. This will affect the queues obviously and make the drivers take alternative routes. The closure and open of roads is a user interaction. The whole intention of the simulation is to realize potential bottlenecks. after I have the simulation up and running I will base the distribution of cars , accidents etc. on real statistical data which I will get a later point. In general I do know the scope of the simulation. I have defined what I want and what I do not want in it.

Comment: If you make collisions probabilistic, the relevant question would be over what area you want to integrate the number of cars (to make chances of collision a function of density). From your description it is clear that there is a) very high-dimensional vector of states for all cars, b) discrete control variables (open/close roads) - in real life there are also varying lights' cycles, c) highly nonlinear equations of motion (an outcome of drivers' solution to nav problem), d) pressing need to run the sim in Monte-Carlo mode since you want conclusions to be robust to outliers.

Comment: Interesting comment. Thanks for this. You have enlightened some areas which I need to think further about. But at first I will aim simple i.e. have one junction with two roads, and a car obeying the traffic lights. Very simple I know but when I have that, I can extend it, because getting the whole animation etc working will also be a challenge for me as I haven't worked much with animation or actually even with Swing that much. So loads of work to do :) I appreciate your time and input.